# How do I run my Flask app remotely using MongoHQ and Heroku (Python)

Tags: python, heroku, flask, tweepy, mongohq

I have a script written in Python that lets me consume tweets from Terminal into a locally hosted mongodb database. To improve uptime, I would like to host this script remotely on Heroku and to shoot the consumed tweets into a database hosted with MongoHQ. As I would like to do this without using Django, I use the Flask framework to deploy the app to Heroku (described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python).

When I run a simple "hello world" app using this setup, everything is fine. However, when I try to run my tweet consuming app, it immediately crashes. How can I change my app to that it will work with the Flask/Heroku/MongoHQ setup? The source code is:

```
import json
import pymongo
import tweepy

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
        super(tweepy.StreamListener, self).__init__()

        self.db = pymongo.MongoClient().test

    def on_data(self, tweet):
        self.db.tweets.insert(json.loads(tweet))

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        return True # Don't kill the stream


sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(api))
sapi.filter(track=['rooney'])
```

I am completely new to programming so I imagine the solution to this problem might well be quite straight forward. However, I am stuck and could really use some help to progress.

Comment: My heroku log is:                                                State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-06T10:07:44.409065+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2013-08-06T10:07:44.409351+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug without more information, but my first guess is that you don't have the dependancies installed.

Heroku gives you a clean python environment. However, you need special libraries like `tweepy` that don't get installed by default. Thus, you have to let Heroku know to install these.

You'll need to use pip and a requirements.txt document which lists out all the libraries that you are trying to use as well as what version numbers.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip

Comment: The second guess is that you are connecting to a database that isn't responding. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r10-boot-timeout